# Save contact to phone from website

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net

I'm currently writing a webpage for friends and family, and one of the features is a "phonebook" that displays everyone's phone number(s), address, etc.

Now if they view this on a phone, either Android or Apple, is there a way they can save a person's information from the website to their phone's contacts?

I'm using asp.net C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can offer a downloadable [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard).

> vCard is a file format standard for electronic business cards. vCards are often attached to e-mail messages, but can be exchanged in other ways, such as on the World Wide Web or instant messaging. They can contain name and address information, phone numbers, e-mail addresses, URLs, logos, photographs, and audio clips.
>   -Wikipedia

There are existing .NET libraries to create vCards. I used [Thought.vCards](http://www.thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/) for one of my projects. I'm not sure I would recommend it again though, I ended up modifying the code a lot. I'd probably just make my own library from scratch next time.

The format itself is pretty easy to understand. The trickiest part for me was converting contact pictures to a format that worked on both iOS and Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Place a button with an href to the link holding the vCard link and it will open the contact up automatically. Ex: https://vcard.link/card/DUo2.vcf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877240)